# removing backslashes in mule 4 dataweave transformation

Tags: json, dataweave

I am fetching data from SQL Server Database and transforming it into JSON in Mule 4. My input has a single backslash and converted to double backslashes. I only need a single backslash in my output.

Input example:

```
abchd\kdgf
```

Output is:

```
"abchd\\kdgf"
```

It should be:

```
"abchd\kdgf"
```

Anyone can help with this data weave transformation?

Comment: Input example:
 abchd\kdgf

Output is:
 abchd\\kdgf

It should be  abchd\kdgf.  

Anyone can help with this data weave transformation?

Comment: The two backslashes represent a single backslash. That's because a "backslash" is used to **escape** special character. For example, if you want to use a double quote in your JSON value then you will have to write `{"specialValue": "quote \" "}`. That is why backslash itself is a special character and thus needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON strings the backslash character is the escape character, and has to be escaped itself to represent a single backlash. That's how JSON works, it is not a Mule issue.

Comment: Yes. It’s a special character. But my requirement is to get the output with single backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Here single slash treated internally as double slash. Try the dataweave expression like below

```
payload replace /([\\])/ with ("")
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: application/dw is meant only for debugging and using it in production applications can cause performance issues. here use application/json